# Microsoft Word - How keep lists from spanning multiple pages

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have some bulleted (and numbered) lists that I would like to prevent from being split across multiple pages.  Rather than have the splitting occur, I would like to have Word automatically put in a page break and start the list on the second page.  Is this possible?

Keep in mind that I don't want to put in the page break manually because if I add text before the list, it might be shifted to the next page anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should be easy.

- Select the entire list
- Right-click and select *Paragraph...*
- Go to the tab *Line and Page Breaks*
- There, select the second and third option (*Keep lines together* and *Keep with next*)

Sorry for not knowing how the option are titled but I'm using a German Word so I don't know how this is labeled in the English version.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, if you apply `Keep with next` to the *last* item in the list, then the *following* paragraph will also be "glued" to the bottom of the list. It feels wrong, but I usually exclude the last item in the list for this reason. Seems there should be a better way...